# asp classic how to take a words or a first letter in a string after specific symbol like @

Tags: string, email, split, asp-classic

I have **test@myword.com** and i want to get the "myword" from this string how to do it?

found this but don't know how to convert to asp

```
String res = email.substring(email.indexOf("@") + 1);
```

i know how to use len left mid and right and split, i believe the answer is a game of those functions but i found no answer in my search of how to.

also if anyone know how to do so with regex as a pattern(just started working with) be much appreciated

THANKS for all the help :)

Answer (score 2):

While [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44626227/447356) is not wrong and will return the first letter after the "@", there is a more generic approach. For this, I'll be using a function that splits a string to multiple parts, based on both "from" and "to" delimeters:

```
Function GetBetween(str, leftDelimeter, rightDelimeter)
    Dim tmpArr, result(), x
    tmpArr=Split(str, leftDelimeter)
    If UBound(tmpArr) < 1 Then
        GetBetween=Array() : Exit Function
    End If
    ReDim result(UBound(tmpArr)-1)
    For x=1 To UBound(tmpArr)
        result(x-1)=(Split(tmpArr(x), rightDelimeter))(0)
    Next
    Erase tmpArr
    GetBetween=result
End Function
```

Now to use it in this specfic case, have such code:

```vbs
Dim email, tempArray
email = "test@myword.com"

'find the word between the "@" and the first dot
tempArray = GetBetween(email, "@", ".")

'check that we got anything:
If UBound(tempArray)<0 Then
    Response.Write("invalid email")
Else  
    'desired word is the first item in the array:
    Response.Write(tempArray(0))
End If

'free allocated memory for dynamic array:
Erase tempArray
```

Answer (score 0):

took some time and a few tries but i found :)

```
email=test@myword.com
response.write mid(email,(inStr(email, "@"))+1,1)
```